# regular expression: r05c75 -- extracting numbers between bookends

Tags: regex

Today, I am learning regular expressions =D

I understand some basics, like `\d+` matches any number of digits, but how would I get the values after 'r' and 'c' in the string `r05c75` (the numbers are arbitrary length)

They represent row and column values and I want to extract the number between 'r' and 'c' and the number between 'c' and $ (end-of-string).

I'm hoping this question will also be elucidative for any other beginners as well.

The general case would be

```
aaa DDD bbb DDD ccc DDD (without spaces)
```

where aaa, bbb, ccc, and ddd are arbitrary (known) strings, and the D-triplets are just digits.

I can "match" (check the validity) of my string r05c75, but I am not sure how to extract the numbers.

This is probably a fairly common question, I'm sorry if I missed any duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:\w+(\d+))+` is the generic regexp that will return only match groups with the digits

The `(?: ... )` syntax signifies a "non-capturing group" which allows me to say that it can repeat (with `+`) but without having it show up in the match groups.  The other group `(\d+)` doesn't have the `?:` and so it is captured.

So, read in English this regexp says, "match a group of one or more of one or more letters followed by one or more digits, and oh yeah capture the digit groupings".

Comment: do you have to explicitly state a non-capturing group if you're using parens to show capturing groups?

Comment: Yes, if you group something with parentheses it will be captured by default.  Using `(?:` makes it not capture.

Answer (score 0):

```
r(\d+)c
```

The parentheses indicate the regular expression concept of a "capture"...if you search your ref docs, they should tell you more about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract values by using parens:

```
r(\d+)c(\d+)
```

This will give you the row number in $1 and the column number in $2.

Answer (score 0):

In general when working with regular expression you have the ability to mark a subexpression a group and after a successful match to retrieve that group contents.

In your case if we user the javascript regex engine you would write the match for `r95c75` as this:

```
var match = "r05c75".match(/r(\d+)c(\d+)/);
if ( match ) // if successfull match
{
  var n1 = match[1];
  var n2 = match[2];
}
```

n1, n2 will contain the numbers.